# Why does my arrow function have a prototype property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, arrow-functions

As mention in document 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

**Arrow functions do not have prototype property**

but when I run this on fiddle, why does it gives an `object`?
http://es6console.com/iwyii5vm/

Why it is giving a object?

```
var Foo = () => {};
console.log(Foo.prototype);
```

Comment: es6console automatically passes your code through babel. If you uncheck es2015 under the presets navigation tab, transform your code again, and click run, `undefined` will be logged as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run this code in a native ES6 engine, there will not be a `prototype` property for arrow functions.

#### Example of native ES6:

```js
var Foo = () => {};
console.log(Foo.prototype);
```

However, if the code is being transpiled to ES5 code, it will not be a true arrow function, and it will have a `prototype` property.

#### Example of ES6 being transpiled with Babel:

(Babel is enabled for this snippet)

```js
var Foo = () => {};
console.log(Foo.prototype);
```

In the case of `es6console.com`, a transpiler is being used, which is why you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: could you please give online editor where you run this code without transpiled ?

Comment: @user944513 Most will do this by default. JSFiddle and CodePen come to mind.

Comment: @user944513 Simply don't select *ES6* as the language. On http://es6console.com/ (whose entire purpose is to provide a babel environment), you'd need un-select the *es2015* preset.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an implementation detail of the way es6console implements es6 features. It works correctly in Chrome, which natively supports arrow functions.

[image]