# How to use arrow functions with main class 'this' properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was racking my brain to make an algorithm in nodeJS work. I got a file with that function bellow where some properties are tied to `this` and some functions are tied to `prototype`.

```
function Main(controller) {
        this.tipo = "string";
        this.controller = controller;
        this.debug = controller.debug;
        this.db = controller.db;
        this.util = require('util');
        this.utils = require('../utils.js');
        this.moment = require('moment');
}

Main.prototype.funcX = (dados) => {
        // doing stuffs
}
```

Somehow, the properties of `this` were not being recognized in functions tied to `prototype` and there was always an TypeError.

Then, I've found a solution after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255943/why-does-my-arrow-function-have-a-prototype-property), where I noticed that arrow function has its own `this` context. Then, changing this code snippet

```
Main.prototype.funcX = (dados) => {
    // doing stuffs
    console.log(typeof this.db) // TypeError: cannot read property 'info' of undefined
};
```

To this

```
 Main.prototype.funcX = function (dados) {
     // doing stuffs 
     console.log(typeof this.db) // prints my db instance
 };
```

made everything works well.

But I do not want to use `function` keyword to these functions at all.

**Q:** What is the best way to use arrow functions accessing the Main's `this` properties?

Comment: you should **not** use arrow function for this.

Comment: Use a normal function. That's not how arrow functions work. Or just define a class instead of using the old-style constructor function.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the whole point of arrow functions - please read some documentation and you'll see that arrow functions are not a replacement for "regular" `function`s - just like a screwdriver is not a replacement for a hammer - the right tool for the job

Comment: I think it's actually correct to throw the error, since the function's "this" is not the Main prototype, but it's parent. To solve the issue, what about using the ES6 Class declarations? You are already using ES6 since you're targeting arrow functions, so I don't exactly see the point to use a prototype in your example. Arrow functions where **not** built for that case, you probably misunderstand why these were implemented. Either use `function`, either use other approaches.

Comment: Arrow functions are not meant to replace functions, they are for different use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is literally no way to access the correct `this` in an arrow function attached to a constructor prototype.

```
"use strict";
function Main() {};
Main.prototype.foo = () => console.log(this);
var m = new Main();
m.foo(); // undefined
m.foo.call(m); // still undefined
m.foo.bind(m)(); // you get the idea
```

Arrow functions' `this` is closed over in the lexical scope like a normal var, and in this case it's the global (or top-level module) scope. If you remove the `"use strict"` you'll just get `window` instead of `undefined`.

You have a few alternatives:

### Don't define on the prototype (don't actually do this):

```
function Main() {
  this.foo = () => console.log(this);
}

m = new Main();
m.foo(); // correct this!
```

This works because the arrow function closes over the correct `this` in the lexical scope of the constructor. But here you lose the advantages of having only one function object shared between instances (since you aren't using the prototype).

### Use a normal function

That's already posted in your question, so no need to repeat.

### Define a class with method

```
class Main {
  foo () {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

m = new Main();
m.foo(); // correct this
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said, **you can't use context with arrow functions**. I guess that the next best bet would be to create an enclosed scope to use inside the arrow function:

```
{ // that
    let db = something;

    Main.prototype.funcX = (dados) => {

        console.log(db + "is only available from inside that block");

    };
}
```

But still, as pointed out in the comments, you're missing the point of arrow functions.